# Why the repeater result not appear in my preview page?

Tags: asp.net

I make code and the repeater catches data but when I preview the page data not appear.
I don't know where the problem is, can any one help me?

***the page code is***

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repSubCategories" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
                         <div class="wrapper3">
                        <section class="left-colP">


                             <br><font color=ea6c05 size="3"><b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Prod_Title")%></b></font><br />
                             <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Company_Name")%><br />
                             <img  class="imgSub"  src="Upload/Product/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Prod_Photo")%>" width=90px height=82px> </section>
                             <aside class="sidebarP"> <font color="ea6c05" size="3"><b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CompDet_Titel")%></b></font><br /><br />
                             <font  size="2"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CompDet_Address")%><br /><br />
                             <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Expr4")%> - <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Expr3")%> - <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Expr1")%>  <br /><br />

                              <asp:Label ID="Label3" CssClass="Telitle1" Text='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("CompDet_Tel")) > 0  ?  "+" + Convert.ToString(Eval("Company_Coad")) + Convert.ToString(Eval("Expr7"))+ Convert.ToString(Eval("CompDet_Tel")): " " %>' runat="server" />
                               <asp:Label ID="Label5" CssClass="Telitle1" Text='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("CompDet_Mob")) > 0  ?  "  +" + Convert.ToString(Eval("Expr7")) + Convert.ToString(Eval("CompDet_Mob")): " " %>' runat="server" />
                           <br /><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CompDet_Web")%><br /><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CompDet_Email")%><br /></font></aside>
                          </div>
                 <br />

           </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater> 

     <center><div class="Counter1">
                             <cc1:collectionpager ID="CollectionPager1" runat="server" BackText="« Previous" 
                                ControlCssClass="current" LabelText="Pages:" MaxPages="1000" 
                                NextText="Next »" PageSize="10" PagingMode="QueryString" 
                                ResultsFormat="Resalt {0}-{1} (from {2})">
                            </cc1:collectionpager>
                            </div></center><br />
```

***code behind***

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            string str = Session["MyCarId"].ToString();

            DataTable dtPrices = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr = dtPrices.NewRow();
            dtPrices.Columns.Add("Prod_Title");
            dtPrices.Columns.Add("Company_Name");
            dtPrices.Columns.Add("CompDet_Titel");
            dtPrices.Columns.Add("CompDet_Address");
            dtPrices.Columns.Add("Expr4");
            dtPrices.Columns.Add("Expr3");
            dtPrices.Columns.Add("Expr1");
            dtPrices.Columns.Add("CompDet_Tel");
            dtPrices.Columns.Add("Company_Coad");
            dtPrices.Columns.Add("Expr7");
            dtPrices.Columns.Add("CompDet_Mob");
            dtPrices.Columns.Add("CompDet_Web");
            dtPrices.Columns.Add("CompDet_Email");
            dtPrices.Columns.Add("Prod_Photo");

            string[] result = Regex.Split(str, ",");
            for (int s = 0; s < result.Length; s++)
            {
                dt = db.ExecSp("AllCompanys", new SqlParameter("DMLType", "GetAllForWebCountry"), new SqlParameter("@Allcomp_country", result[s]));


                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    dr["Prod_Title"] = dt.Rows[j]["Prod_Title"].ToString();
                    dr["Company_Name"] = dt.Rows[j]["Company_Name"].ToString();
                    dr["CompDet_Titel"] = dt.Rows[j]["CompDet_Titel"].ToString();
                    dr["CompDet_Address"] = dt.Rows[j]["CompDet_Address"].ToString();
                    dr["Expr4"] = dt.Rows[j]["Expr4"].ToString();
                    dr["Expr3"] = dt.Rows[j]["Expr3"].ToString();
                    dr["Expr1"] = dt.Rows[j]["Expr1"].ToString();
                    dr["CompDet_Tel"] = dt.Rows[j]["CompDet_Tel"].ToString();
                    dr["Company_Coad"] = dt.Rows[j]["Company_Coad"].ToString();
                    dr["Expr7"] = dt.Rows[j]["Expr7"].ToString();
                    dr["CompDet_Mob"] = dt.Rows[j]["CompDet_Mob"].ToString();
                    dr["CompDet_Web"] = dt.Rows[j]["CompDet_Web"].ToString();
                    dr["CompDet_Email"] = dt.Rows[j]["CompDet_Email"].ToString();
                    dr["Prod_Photo"] = dt.Rows[j]["Prod_Photo"].ToString();

                }

            }
            dtPrices.Rows.Add(dr);
            repSubCategories.Visible = true;
            CollectionPager1.DataSource = dtPrices.DefaultView;
            CollectionPager1.BindToControl = repSubCategories;
            repSubCategories.DataSource = CollectionPager1.DataSourcePaged;
            repSubCategories.DataBind();
            Label1.Text = "&nbsp; &nbsp;" + dt.Rows.Count + " search results";

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a new row for each item, so your code would be structured like

```
for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
{
    dr = dtPrices.NewRow();
    // populate dr...
    dtPrices.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: OK, can you check that `result.Length` and `dt.Rows.Count` are greater than zero? If they are, then you could comment out the `for (int s = 0; s < result.Length; s++)` block and put in some fake data to make sure that the rest of the code is correct.